# I get a null error when I try to run my flutter app after trying to fetch data from a url

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I get the error below after modifying my home page on my app to the code as shown below, I get the error in my object_patch.dart file. I don't know how that can be resolved. what could I have done wrong?

**Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: )** (see image)

[image]

[image]

````
import 'package:awsome_app/drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  //Functions here now

  // var myText = "This is a function";
  // TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();

  var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
  var data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() async {
    var res = await http.post(Uri.parse(url));
    data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    setState(() {});
    ;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(204, 255, 249, 249),
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Welcome to Flutter App")),
      body: data != null
          ? ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(data[index]["title"]),
                );
              },
              itemCount: data.length,
            )
          : Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: In the debug window, on the left, you can see that the problem is in `build`, but you don't show that method. Even so, I can guess the issue: `data` is null. `build` will be called at least once before `fetchData` has completed (and assigned a value to `data`), and it will encounter that null value. You need to allow for that by testing whether `data` is null. If it is display, for example, a progress indicator. If it is not, build instead the widget tree based on the data. (See also `FutureBuilder`.)

Comment: I have had to edit the question to make you see if you can debug, please. I am new and trying to build my first app before I get into details. I want to have a general overview of the whole thing before I start taking the detailed dart programming classes. I will also like your your instruction of what i should do to solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos will return a list of photos.

Replace

```
var res = await http.post(Uri.parse(url));
```

with

```
var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: What can i do to get rid of the error?

Comment: solved. I loved you mehn.... Thanks so much. I guess my eyes are not trained well enough for coding yet. You rock. Appreciated.